# Возможно ли потом удалить выделенную память?

Tags: stl, c++

Есть такая не прозрачная для меня штука:

```
DATA *d = new DATA();
data.push_back(*d);
```

Вопрос в том, что возможно ли потом удалить выделенную память?
Что тут происходит: data - глобальная, все остальное - нет.
Выделяется память под обьект класса DATA и сохраняется начало адреса на этот обьект.
Потом этот обьект, как я понимаю, КОПИРУЕТСЯ в data? заталкивается в нее...
после вызова push_back выталкивается копия обьекта, а память выделенная new DATA(); не освобождается.  Я прав? Если да, то как сделать так, чтобы можно было освобождать память? Подскажите, верно ли мыслю или что-то не так.

Comment: Тема вопроса не отражает содержание. Это как "вопрос по С++". И содержание новичковое, если вектор объектов, а не указателей, то хранить он будет копию объекта, а не указатели. Не понимаю, за что плюс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в вектор будет скопирован объект. Поэтому, память нужно освободить. Но есть один маленький нюанс - должен быть правильный конструктор копирования (его компилятор может создать автоматически при необходимости, но не всегда он будет делать именно то, что нужно).

Рассмотрим такой пример:

```
class DATA {
   private:
     int m;
     int * n;
   //....
   ~DATA() {
      delete n;
    }
}
```

Если конструкторов нет, компилятор сгенерирует их сам. переменную `m` он скопирует правильно, тут проблем нет. А вот переменную `n` он скопирует как указатель. В деструкторе переменная `n` удаляется и скопированный объект получит "висящий указатель", что и приведет к ошибке. Гарантировано приведет к ошибке, когда нужно будет удалить скопированный объект (если к этому времени никто не занулит переменную n).

Как быть в подобных ситуациях?

- аккуратно реализовывать все конструкторы и деструктор
- использовать умные указатели
- самому реализовать учет ссылок (это хардкор путь, но иногда он оправдан. Но в целом, есть готовый умный указатель, которому нужно только прописать, как считать ссылки).

Comment: Мне кажется в данном случае достаточно было посоветовать разместить d на стеке =)

Comment: не факт - человек явно написал, что DATA - глобальная.

Comment: Спасибо) Все понял)